# .net core controller JWT token disappear after await

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, bearer-token

I have an application with JWT token authorization.
JWT token contains information about user role and additional user information which are stored in Claims.

After *await* user token information disappear.

Is this default behavior? How to obtain User's information after await? Yes, there is a simple workaround -> save information to the variable before *await*, but it looks strange to me.

My controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProjectDomainService _projectDomainService;
    public ProjectController(IProjectDomainService projectDomainService)
    {
        _projectDomainService = projectDomainService;
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public async void CreateProject([FromBody] ProjectDto project)
    {
        var claims = User.Claims; //contains 11 claims
        await Task.Delay(100);
        claims = User.Claims; // contains 0 claims
    }
}
```

Edit1: replaced call to projectDomainService with Task.Delay(). The same behavior - Claims are empty after await.

Comment: Can you replace `_projectDomainService.CreateAsync(project);` with `Task.Delay(100)` or `Task.Run(x=> Thread.Sleep(100))` and update code in the post accordingly  to confirm there is nothing fishy in `CreateAsync`?

Comment: Code updated, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: You should *never* use `async void` in ASP.NET Core. Change `void` to `Task` here and it'll work.

Comment: It really works. But what's wrong with *void* that it causes such a problem?

Comment: By returning `void`, the ASP.NET Core framework doesn't know when you've finished handling the request, which means it thinks you've finished *earlier than you have*. Returning the `Task` ensures everything stays alive until you're actually done.

Comment: Thanks for explanation